# EF LINQ select entities where Id is in List

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I was trying to select a list of  entities using EF and Linq and I should retrieve only those that has a specific AccountId inside the Participants ICollection

```
public class Conversation
{
    public Conversation()
    {
        Participants = new List<Account>();
        Messages = new List<Message>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Int32 conversationId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Account> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

_Db is DbContext

```
public async Task<List<Conversation>> FindByAccountIdAsync(Int32 id)
{
   return await _Db.Conversations.Where(....).ToListAsync(); 
   // .... select conversations where id == AccountId inside ICollection<Account> Participants
}
```

I have no idea on how to compose the query in LINQ

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.95).aspx):

```
return await _Db.Conversations
    .Where(c => c.Participants.Any(p => p.Id == id))
    .AsQueryable()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks David I get an error that says:  System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: It's obviously too late in the day, ignore the previous idea and use this one instead, much simpler anyway.

Comment: Thanks David I still get an error 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Application.Models.Conversation>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Application.Models.Conversation>'

Comment: I guess you should make change your List like
Participants = IEnumerable<Account>(); Or IQueryable for use ToListAsync();

Comment: @Gavello Added in an extra line to enable you to do `ToListAsync`